# Bit shifting with enums

Tags: c#, byte, bit

I have 4 properties and want to shift them in a byte called controlByte. The TypeEnum for example has 4 entries (0 = Unknown, 1 = Red, 2 = Blue, 3 = Green)

- Bit 0-1: TypeEnum
- Bit 2-3: SpeedEnum
- Bit 4: IsActive
- Bit 5: Optional

Code:

```
 Byte controlByte = 0;
 controlByte  = (byte) (controlByte  | ((int)TypeEnum << 0));
 controlByte  = (byte) (controlByte  | ((int)SpeedEnum  << 2));
 controlByte  = (byte) (controlByte  | (IsActive ? 1 : 0 << 4));
```

Expected Result:

```
     | Optional | IsActive | Speed | Type |
 Bit 7          5          4       2      0
```

I'm not sure if the logic with the enums is correct. But the 3rd line with IsActive doesn't work. The Bit with index 0 is set instead of the Bit with index 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
controlByte  = (byte) (controlByte  | ((IsActive ? 1 : 0) << 4));
```

Your conditional reads like this: IsActive? then 1, not active then (0 with 4 left shift) a.k.a 0